# Complex Analysis Book

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want a really good book on Complex Analysis, for a **good** understanding of theory. There are many complex variable books that are only a list of identities and integrals and I hate it. For example, I found Munkres to be a very good book for learning topology, and "Curso de Análise vol I" by Elon Lages Lima is the best Real Analysis book (and the best math book) that I have read with many examples, good theory and challenging exercises.

An intuitive and introductory approach is not very important if the book has good explanations and has correct proofs.

**Added:** If it is possible, tell me your experience with your recommended books and if you got a really good understanding of complex analysis with a **deep** reading.

Comment: See the question, ["What is a good complex analysis textbook?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook).

Comment: probably any book of this topic satisfies the kind of book of what I was looking, I don't want an intermediary book with an application approach.

Comment: @GastónBurrull The analysis book by Lima that you have mentioned, does it have an english version?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth No, only in portuguese. But you can read "courant and john introduction to calculus and analysis" it is excellent and it is very similar to lima.

Comment: @GastónBurrull I do not like analysis. I am past under graduation. But I want to give it a try if I can find some gem of a book, otherwise I guess its too late for me..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Conway, "Functions of One Complex Variable I" http://books.google.ca/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C

Comment: Looks good, and it is avaible in my university library. I'll check it.

Comment: Im looking Conway preview and looks very good with a topologycal and metric spaces early approachs. Probably this is my book.

Comment: I second that. Excellent choice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see it with Alfors in my university and I'll decide for one, probably I'll decide for Conway.

Comment: I've always felt Conway was overrated. It's ok,but pretty dry and it misses a lot of the beautiful geometry of the complex plane. It's probably the second volume that really impressed most people-the material in THAT book isn't readily available in a lot of sources.

Answer (score 23):

My biggest recommendation is Tristan Needham's [Visual Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534469). Although not a strict textbook, all of the traditional theorems in elementary complex analysis are covered. Proofs aren't thorough, but are instead explained geometrically in general outlines. The big advantage with this book is the massive amount of pictures, nearly on every page in some sections.

Other great classics are Rudin's [Real and Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542341), Conway's [Functions of One Complex Variable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387903283). For a thorough but relatively intuitive approach, I also heavily recommend Sarason's [Complex Function Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821844288).

Comment: I think that Tristan's book is not the book that I was looking. But Conways looks good. What about Rudin, which topics cover it?.

Comment: Rudin is interested in showing you how clever he is. Conway gets you to believe that you can do this yourself. Sarason is an insightful man of few words, and every one of them counts.

Answer (score 16):

The followings are very, very good. Note that you should start with the first one if you are a beginner.

- Reinhold Remmert. *Theory of complex functions*. Springer 1991.
- Reinhold Remmert. *Classical topics in complex function theory*. Springer 2010.

Comment: Can I read the second one helping with the first one?

Comment: I would recommend starting with the first one, and you will know when you need to get the second one.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I'll start with the both and Conway and I'll decide which book I will definitely read.

Comment: In case it helps, here are some lecture notes I produced when I taught a complex analysis course: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math566f10/?Lecture_notes

Comment: thanks for your proper material =)

Answer (score 13):

The books below are excellent:

- [Invitation to Complex Analysis](http://www.maa.org/pubs/ICA.html) by Ralph P. Boas (second edition revised by Harold P. Boas).
- [Complex Made Simple](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-97) by David C. Ullrich.

Comment: Both looks so good, for my level, thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen either,but I'm told Ulrich is outstanding.

Answer (score 13):

A very classic book to learn complex analysis from is [Ahlfors's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070006571) (which I used). There is also [Stein and Shakarchi's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113858), and [Bak and Newman's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441972870).

Comment: I've heard about Ahlfor's, is really a good book? Do you full understand the basic topics with a deep reading? Has challenger problems? Tell me about your own experience.

Comment: @GastónBurrull I thought it was a good book but definitely on the tough side. It's not like Churchill's book which is more geared towards applications, this is intent on rigor. The exercises I thought were challenging but that's a relative opinion. It's pricey but there's an international edition which is a lot cheaper (about $20).

Comment: @GastónBurrull Another thing is Ahlfors isn't heavy on examples. If you like lots of examples then maybe you won't like Ahlfors. In my opinion, which may be controversial, is that this is the baby Rudin of complex analysis.

Comment: Ahlfors looks very good but some difficult and not many examples I'll get it in my library is avaible I'll check it with conway (both are avaible in my university library) and I'll decide for one.

Comment: I strongly suggest the book by Bak and Newman. I learned complex analysis there, and I still believe it is a wonderful textbook for undergrads.

Comment: @Gaston NO,Gaston,it's NOT a good book. It's just been enshrined by people who had the misfortune of being graduate students when there weren't a lot of choices for textbooks at that level.That and Ahlfors was one of the preeminient function theorists of the 20th century-which creates a lot of misplaced reverence. The third and final edition was a VAST improvement over the first-which was an unreadable abomination-but still not a great book by any means.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one that I love: Donald Sarason's book, Complex Function Theory. It's beautifully and economically written, so that it really flows. It was published by Henry Helson in his garage for a long time, but has been taken over by the American Math. Soc.

It covers complex analysis up to and including some advanced topics such as the Riemann mapping theorem, starting from basic real analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion and experience.

Comment: It's a bit terse for my tastes, but I agree,this is quite a nice book if that's your cup of potion.

Answer (score 8):

Ahlfors, [*Complex Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070006571).  It is an absolute classic and, while spartan-seeming, is a fantastic introduction to the course.  It was actually my second introduction to the subject (I had it at an earlier undergraduate level using Churchill & Brown, which isn't bad, but no classic.)  That book, coupled with an amazing instructor, made a huge impact.

Answer (score 7):

I had really good luck with [Fisher's Complex Variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486406792) and [Gamelin's Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950699).

Comment: What do you mean with really good luck?, what is the approach?

Comment: Books looks good and basic with many examples thanks!

Comment: Really good luck means that I was taking a graduate complex analysis course that used Ahlfors.  I floundered horribly until I studied from the two books mentioned.  Fisher was thorough, but it wasn't comprehensive enough.  Gamelin helped me make up the difference between Fisher and where I needed to be.

Comment: +1 for 2 great books. The former is a classic in a wonderful cheap Dover edition and the latter is on it's way to becoming a classic. My one quibble with Gamelin is that it tends to be a little TOO soft for a graduate course at times, especially early in the book. But that's what makes it ideal for self study. It really starts from jump,unlike most books-even honors high school students could use the early chapters!

Answer (score 7):

Look up this free complex analysis  book by Shabbat http://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/shabat-all.pdf

Answer (score 6):

[Elias Wegert](http://visual.wegert.com/)'s book:
 [Visual Complex Functions: An Introduction Using Phase Portraits](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-0348-0179-9) might not be so good for analytic techniques, but I've found it to be really good for honing one's intuition. (it's the first of a planned two volume set).

Answer (score 5):

I think Serge Lang's book on Complex Analysis is a good a one to go with.

[http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387985921](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985921)

Answer (score 5):

No one has mentioned here, but 'A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications' by [zill](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Kyg6_v7cif8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Zill+and+shanahan&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KjhZVPr_OY6ruQSJh4LIAQ&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Zill%20and%20shanahan&f=false) is my favourite book. It is so clear and comprehensive, and much simpler and intutive explainantions.

Comment: From the authors taste in Munkres, I expect he was looking for a graduate book.  However, I did use this book as an undergraduate.  I do still have Zills book on DE too.

Answer (score 5):

Complex Analysis, by Beardon is unmatched in quality. I put it above Ahlfors, because in the preface of Ahlfors CA, Allen F Beardon is mentioned with gratitude.

Comment: I've never seen that book! How could Beardon have written a complex analysis text and I didn't know?

Answer (score 4):

as my opinion s.ponnusamy ''foundation of complex analysis'' is the best book.
same concepts are taught in simple and different way.

Answer (score 4):

[Complex Analysis](http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/complex-analysis-0) by Kunihiko Kodaira

Answer (score 3):

An Introduction to Complex Analysis 
by Ravi P. Agarwal , Kanishka Perera , Sandra Pinelas 
is a fantastic book!

Comment: I found this book to be the most infuriating. Eventually got tired of filling in the gaps in the steps. Does not develop any intuition. Produces key concepts like the exponential form like a rabbit out of the hat instead of motivating them. The only redeeming quality is solutions to exercises.