# Reference request for complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

My curriculum for math has the first chapter on **complex variables**. It is as stated below:

> Functions of complex variables:
>
> - Continuity and derivability of a function
> - Analytic functions
> - Necessary condition for $f(z)$ to be analytic, sufficient conditions (without
>   proof)
> - Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form
> - Harmonic functions
> - Orthogonal trajectories
> - Analytical and Milne-Thomson method to find $f(z)$ from its real or
>   imaginary parts.
> - Complex integration
> - Taylor’s and Laurent’s series (without proof)
> - Cauchy’s residue theorem (statement & application)

I have been able to locate some of it on [MIT OpenCourseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/part-i/) but I am not sure if that will be enough.

Can someone please point me out to more resources for this chapter ?

Comment: See also: [Complex Analysis Book](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160132/49437) and [What is a good complex analysis textbook?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30749/49437)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Bak & Newman's "Complex Analysis" for an introduction to the above topics except for "CR in polar form", "harmonic functions"  and "Milne-Thomson".

Comment: What is orthogonal trajectories ?

Comment: @LittleChild  I thought it was something about conformal maps "lines to lines and circles to circles" and related topics

Comment: Out of curiosity: It is the second time today that I see you mention Bak's and Newman's names in reverse order. Is there a particular reason for doing this?

Comment: @Martin yes: because I am lazy and I did a copy paste :-). I edit it now, thanks

Comment: Oh, okay. Fair enough :-)

Comment: @Avitus OK fine, I had a look at the book. I didn't grasp a thing :-D

Comment: @LittleChild you mean chapter 13? Complex analysis is a false friend...I find it very tricky!

Comment: @Avitus Churchill's book on Complex Variables has everything :)

Comment: @LittleChild really? Great!