# Textbook +reference book in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

Which book can be used as an introductory textbook in complex analysis?

I have some choices (more suggestions are welcomed)

1. Marsden & Hoffman
2. J.B. Conway
3. Ahlfors
4. Palka
5. Lang
6. Stein & Shakarchi

I want a textbook which is affordable,builds my concepts and lays a strong foundation of complex analysis.the book should cover the concepts that are needed in a complex analysis course in a formidable manner.Also it should be such that I can use it for an exam

Also I would be happy if someone can provide me  a reference book that can be used side by side with the textbook for studying in more detail

Comment: It will probably depend on your level of experience. Is this for undergraduate- or graduate-level study?

Comment: graduate level study @MPW

Comment: I recommend Conway, but am admittedly biased because that's what I used. It can be a little difficult if you don't have several courses in rigorous analysis behind you, but it is quite well written in my opinion. If you have really never seen complex variables before, I would recommend an easy undergraduate course (or text) first, just so you can not have to struggle with learning the fundamentals while also wrestling with the advanced level of mathematics in a graduate text. I think you could absolutely gobble up an easy text first, then you'd be more prepared for the heavier stuff.

Comment: Imho: stay away from Ahlfors as introductory *text* book, though it can be a very good  reference book. Conway is very good, and I also like Freitag-Busam's "Complex analysis, and Remmert's "Theory of Complex functions" (**not** his "Topics..."  as this last is more advanced!)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160132/complex-analysis-book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Schaum's outline of complex variables by M. Spiegel
- Introduction to complex analysis by H.A.Priestly
- Introductory complex analysis by R. Silverman
- Complex analysis by J. Howie
- Complex analysis by J. Bok
- Elementary real and complex analysis by G. Shilov

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this rather new text.

Complex Analysis with Applications by Asmar, Nakhlé H., Grafakos, Loukas ( https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319940625 )

It is more 'visual' than the praised 'Visual Complex Analysis' because it has +/- 385 very good illustrations.