# Reference book of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, reference-works

Please tell me a good reference book of complex analysis. I am a postgraduate student. I really need this. I want to strong my basic concepts from starting. So please  help me ..... 
Now I am reading complex analysis by 'kasana'

Comment: Have you gone through the recommendations already given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160132/complex-analysis-book?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook?rq=1) or the related questions that appear on the right hand side of your computer screen (assuming of course that you are viewing this site via a computer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the three books I study from:

- S. Ponnusamy, Herb Silverman - Complex Variables with Applications.
- Ravi P. Agarwal - An Introduction to Complex Analysis.
- Jerrold E. Marsden, Michael J. Hoffman - Basic Complex Analysis

Answer (score 4):

The following are good books of complex Analysis,you can have a look at them and decide which one suits  to your taste:

**1:** Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis.

**2:** Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi

**3:** Complex Analysis by Ahlfors

**4:** Theory of Complex Functions by Reinhold Remmert