# Analytic function with all derivatives bounded at a point in an open connected set.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on an open connected set $D$. Suppose there is a point $w \in D$ such that $|f^n(w)| \leq n$ for all $n$. Then, there exists an entire function $g$ such that $g = f$ on $D$.

I already have a proof of this, but I am looking to read further. I will be very grateful if someone can tell me the name of this theorem or link me to lecture notes that contains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this result has a name; it is an elementary exercise, suitable for undergraduate homework in complex analysis. (A special case of the formula $R=1/\limsup |c_n|^{1/n}$ for the radius of convergence; here $c_n=f^{(n)}(w)/n!$.) Other bounds on the derivatives could be given that have the same effect.

Recommendations for complex analysis textbooks can be found, e.g., in  [What is a good complex analysis textbook?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30749/) It would not be a good idea to base the choice of your further reading on this particular exercise.