# Determining if a function is real anaytic at the point $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, analyticity

Is there a method, other then using refer to the Taylor series to determine if a real function is analytic at the point $a$. If so please, if possible, could you give a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient method I know is to show that $f$ extends to a [holomorphic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)   in a neighborhood of $a$ in the complex plane. The property of being holomorphic can be verified just by considering the first order derivatives (the Cauchy-Riemann equations). It implies, by a theorem of complex analysis (see [any textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30749/147263)), that the function is represented by a power series.

#### Example

Consider the function $f(x)=1/(x^2+1)$ near the point  $x=1$. Its natural extension to the complex plane is $$F(x+iy) = \frac{1}{(x+iy)^2+1}$$ which is holomorphic as long as $x+iy\notin \{-i,i\}$.  In particular, $F$ is holomorphic in the open disk of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at $1$. It follows that $F$ is represented by a power series centered at $1$ with radius of convergence $\sqrt{2}$. Restricting attention to the real line again, conclude that $f$ is represented by a power series,
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-1)^n,\qquad |x-1|<\sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: This kind of a proof, from real to complex back to real, is what the [well-known quote by Hadamard](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jorgen/hadamardquotesource.html) is about.