# Reference request for a translated Complex Analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently trying to self-learn Complex Analysis as it isn't available for me to take as a course at university in my current year.

I'm trying to decide with which textbook I should use that would help me learn best without having a lecturer.

I asked one of my professors, and he recommended me a list of books, but he noted that there is one book written in German by **Klaus Jänich for real and complex analysis "Funktionentheorie: Eine Einführung"** (As seen here: [Funktionentheorie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540203923) ) . Unfortunately, I do not speak German and thus would not be able to learn from it.

He mentioned that he wasn't very knowledgeable about many other textbooks, but he felt like this was a go-to book for him, as he found it most intuitive and well thought.

Some of the authors he described were D.N Arnold and M. Taylor.

**My question is:** Does anyone know where I can find a translated version of the text by Jänich? Or for anyone who has worked with this text, if you could suggest an English text that teaches in a similar manner? Or in general, your thoughts and opinions on this text, or if another textbook might be better suited for me to learn Complex Analysis on my own (Possibly Rudin, Palka, Needham, Ahlfors, Conway)?

I'm currently using the following website to decide which textbook would be best to pursue: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

If it's any help, I also self-learned Real Analysis, so that might hinder me a bit delving further into Analysis.

Many thanks for the insight and help =)

Comment: This happen to me some times... I want to read some books that, unfortunately, had been published only in german. Probably the best path to follow is trying to learn a bit of german (I tried) but it is a complicated language in many ways from my native language (spanish). I would like to read too this Jänich's book some day. Good look with your search.

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for the input. I hope that I would be able to learn German in the near future, although it's not something I think I can accomplish right now.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook?rq=1) for a lot of very good recommendations concerning complex analysis.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, I will look into that. Hopefully, someone will come and let me know if there is a translated version at all. Appreciate the link =)

Answer (score 0):

I used Needham's VCA to self study complex analysis a few years ago and I found it to be a wonderful book - I highly highly recommend it