# Modern complex analysis book (any suggestions ?)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can someone suggest any modern books for complex analysis (in pdf if possible)? With nice looking text and formulas, examples, chapters, chapter reviews and so on. It is easier and more interesting for me to learn from these kinds of books.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there are tons of questions asking for reference on complex analysis, see this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook-barring-ahlforss

Comment: I will probably find something nice here. Thanks!