# Ahlfors Complex Analysis - Directed line segment

Tags: complex-analysis

In his book on Complex Analysis, Ahlfors on Page $17$ writes:

- "*A directed line $z = a + bt$ determines a right half plane
  consisting of all points $z$ with $\Im \left(\frac{z - a}b\right) <
     0$ and a left half plane with $\Im \left(\frac{z - a}b\right) > 0$*"

Why does Ahlfors use $\Im$ with $\frac{z - a}b$?

I thought $t = \frac{z - a}b$ belongs to Reals. So $\frac{z - a}b>0$ would represents the Right Half and $\frac{z - a}b<0$ the Left Half of the plane.

Definitely I'm missing something since Ahlfors is using Im with $\frac{z - a}b$.

Answer (score 3):

The operation

$$z \to \frac {z-a}b$$

corresponds to a *translation* of $-a$ (that is $a$ goes at the origin) and a *rotation* of an angle equal to $\theta =-\arg (b)$ in such way that the line $z=a+bt$ goes onto the real axis and therefore we can conclude according to the statement given by Ahlfors.

Comment: Thanks. If we are mapping onto the Real Line, why do we use Right Hand and Left Hand Plane and not Upper Half and Lower Half. Apologies if the question is a bit silly.

Comment: @sidharth It's a good question. I think that the terminology used by Ahlfors refers to an observer moving along the positive direction of the "directed line". In this sense the points with $\Im(z)>0$ lie on the left hand.

Comment: Thanks!! Very Helpful

Comment: Also can you suggest a book as rigourous as Ahlfors but where I dont have to struggle so much with explanations. Am learning maths on my own.

Comment: You can refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30749/505767

Comment: Its a long list :) Thanks anyways.
Your explanations were really helpful. Dont think I would have understood on my own

Comment: You are welcome! Bye